# Matlab equivalent to Apply in Mathematica

Tags: arrays, matlab, list, parameter-passing

I'm looking for an equivalent in Matlab to do the same as `Apply` in Mathematica. There it works like this

```
fct=#1+#2^2+#3^3+#4^4&;
Apply[fct,{a,b,c,d}]=f[a,b,c,d]
```

In Matlab, it's easy with a cell like this

```
fct=@(x1,x2,x3,x4) x1+x2^2+x3^3+x4^4;
mycell={a,b,c,d};
fct(mycell{:})
```

because `mycell{:}=a,b,c,d` is a valid comma-separated list of arguments for `fct` (see [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)).

Now, I would like to do the same with an array, e.g. like this:

```
myarrray=[a,b,c,d];
fct(myarray(:))
```

but this doesn't work. Sadly, things like `fct(num2cell(myarray){:})` don't work either.
The problem here is that I would like to use the function as a one-liner (the array already exists, it can be called by its name). The reason for this is that the function should be an element of a struct.

Of course, in reality, my function looks differently. Note that I'm not looking for `arrayfun` which maps a function over an array.

(side note: In Mathematica, I can even write  `Apply[#1+#2^2+#3^3+#4^4&,{a,,b,c,d}]` and there is even an infix notation for `Apply` making it more concise.)

Comment: Why does it have to be in one line? Why can't you redefine `fct`? Why can't you make `fct` its own function?

Comment: Why not just pass the array and vectorize the function?

Comment: @excaza because I'd like to add it to a struct like e.g. `mystruct.myfct=@x fct(x(:))`and then use it on an array: `mystruct.myfct(myarray)`

Comment: @beaker can you post an example?

Comment: I don't understand how that precludes you from redefining `fct` to accept an array: `fct=@(x) x(1)+x(2)^2+x(3)^3+x(4)^4;`

Comment: `fct=@(A) sum(A.^[1 2 3 4]);`

Comment: @excaza For the sake of legibility (also because of conventions), the function actually looks like this `@(A,B,C,D,E,F,lam)sqrt(1+A*lam^2/(lam^2-B)+C*lam^2/(lam^2-D)+E*lam^2/(lam^2-F))` and I would like to apply it to different sets of values for `A..F` to abtain functions of `lam`. As the parameters are always called, `A..F` I wanted to avoid using `x(1)` etc.

 @beaker and this is why a vectorization is not so simple here

Comment: If you're worried about legibility then you shouldn't be attempting to stuff something like this into a one-liner. You're not using Twitter as an IDE.

Comment: @excaza I find the function quite legible. But how to put a non-one-liner into a struct then? I would like to export the struct to a file to be able to share it. Is this a too bad idea?

Comment: Well, you could always convert the array to a cell and use your solution above, or put a wrapper function around this that takes an array and splits it out `@(A) fct(A(1), A(2), A(3), ...);` Not particularly elegant, perhaps, but it would at least preserve some legibility in your function.

Comment: the wrapper function is something I'm looking for. So if I understand you right, the answer to my question is "there is not inbuilt function". In the end it would be nicest to have a universal wrapping function to work with all sorts of functions.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's anything directly equivalent. You could make the wrapper more generic by passing both the array and the function to call, but you'd be limited to scalar function arguments.